# Unable To Add Angular Material To Angular Custom Library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I want to build a custom library based on angular material library so i added angular material to my angular project and tested material components in my components it worked well. But after i tried to use angular material in library created VIA ng generate library then i was flooded with errors.

Errors:

```
BUILD ERROR
: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tab'.
1. If 'mat-tab' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<div class="pwc-tabs">
  <mat-tab-group disableRipple>
    <mat-tab  [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let tab of tabContent" label="{{tab.title}}"> {{tab.content}} </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>

")
```

i tried to add material modules in library imports and exports nothing worked

tabs.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TabsComponent } from './tabs.component';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TabsComponent],
  imports: [
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    TabsComponent
  ]
})
export class TabsModule { }
```

tabs.html

```
<div class="tabs">
  <mat-tab-group disableRipple>
    <mat-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabContent" label="{{tab.title}}"> {{tab.content}} </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>

  <mat-expansion-panel #tabsExpansionPanel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <i *ngIf="!tabsExpansionPanel.expanded" class="material-icons expansion-panel-icons">
          keyboard_arrow_down
        </i>
        <i *ngIf="tabsExpansionPanel.expanded" class="material-icons expansion-panel-icons">
          keyboard_arrow_up
        </i>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header> 
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</div>
```

Comment: check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gufm6g

Comment: Woking well in component. But not working in custom library. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add CommonModule to the imports of your tabs.module.ts